# Dynamic Camel route configuration at deployment time: Java DSL or XML DSL?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Let me preface this with the fact that I am still very new to Apache Camel. I'm still trying to understand how it all works, and what needs to be done (and HOW to do it) to achieve a particular effect.

I am trying to develop a Spring Boot application that will use Apache Camel to handle the transmission (and possibly also receipt) of data to/from a number of possible sources and destinations. The purpose of the application is to provide a means to produce/generate network traffic, *at the network application level*, that will be fed into another Spring Boot application - let's call this the target. We are trying to observe and measure the effects various network loads have on the target.

We would like to be able to transmit data via a number of protocols, including: ftp, http/s, file systems (nfs), various mail protocols (smtp, pop) and data streaming protocols for voice and video. There may be other protocols added at a later time. The data itself is irrelevant, we just need to be able to transmit data via various protocols with various loads.

These applications/services will be running in a containerized environment (Docker) that will be run within our local development and test environment, as well as possibly in a cloud environment, such as AWS. We have used Docker, Ansible, Terraform and are currently working towards using Kubernetes and Istio to manage the configuration, deployment, and operation of these applications.

**We need to be able to provide specific configurations of Camel routes for particular deployments.**

It would appear that the preferred method to configure Camel routes is via Java DSL, rather than XML DSL. The Camel documentation and nearly every other source of information I've found have a strong bias towards using Java DSL. Examples of XML DSL route configuration are far and few.

My initial impression is that going the Java DSL route (excuse the pun), would not work well with our need to be able to deploy a Camel application with a specific route configuration. It seems like you are required to have Java DSL defined route configurations hardwired into the code.

We think that it will be easier to provide a specific route configuration via an XML file that can be included in a deployment, hence why I've been trying to investigate and experiment with XML DSL. Perhaps we are mistaken in this regard.

**My question to the community is**: Considering what I've described above, can the Java DSL approach be used to meet the requirements as I've described them? Can we use Java DSL in a way that allows for dynamic route configuration? Keep in mind we would not be attempting to change configuration during operation, just in the course of performing a deployment.

If Java DSL *could* be used for this purpose, it would be very much appreciated if pointers to documentation, examples, etc. could be provided.

Answer (score 1):

For your use cases you could use XML DSL also.  Anyhow below book covers most aspects Camel development with examples. In this book authors describes XML DSL use for most of java DSL examples. 
https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition
In below github repository you can find the source code for all the examples listed in above book. 
https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2

Simple tutorial and github repository for Apache Camel using Spring boot.
https://www.baeldung.com/apache-camel-spring-boot
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-camel

Maven Plugin for build and deployment of spring boot container application into Kubernetes cluster
https://maven.fabric8.io/

In case if your company can afford some funding for your effort look at below link which provides commercial offerings around Camel. 
https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/commercial-camel-offerings.html

Thanks
Madhu Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Our team has a few projects which use the Java DSL for building routes. In order to make them dynamic, there are control structures for iterating and setting endpoints based off configurations. That works for us because the routes are basically all the same, just with different sources and sinks.

If you could dynamically add/change the XML DSL files in a way that doesn't involve redeploying your application, that might be a viable route to follow. One might, for example, change the `camel.springboot.xml-routes` property to point to a folder which changes as needed.